# Making multiple lines of text inline with an image

Tags: css

How can you make multiple lines of text (`a`) inline with an image (`img`)?

The second line of the text is always placed after the image.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="entry">
  <img class="icon" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png">
  <a class="name">Waisie Milliams Hah Waisie Milliams Hah</a>
  <div class="num">0</div>
</div>

<style>
  .entry {
    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    margin: 6.9px;
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 224px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    perspective-origin: 112px 200.188px;
    transform-origin: 112px 200.188px;
    caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    min-height: 220px;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .name {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .num {
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 112px;
  }
</style>
```

I have tried messing around with the `display` property on both the container and the two children, but with no luck.

Comment: float:left on the image

Comment: (Question updated)
That changes the position of the `.num` element and makes it no longer centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <img class="icon" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png">
     <a class="name">Waisie Milliams Hah Waisie Milliams Hah</a>
  </div>
   <div class="num">0</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my original question with some more details.
Adding `display: flex;` makes the `.num` element disappear.

https://i.imgur.com/QHTA2cB.png

Comment: ok then remove flex from .entry class and add my updated html in your code...

Comment: This works pretty well. Is there a way to also center the text vertically without knowing how many lines it has? `vertical-align: middle` doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Yes you can, i updated my code as per your requirement check it once, if works fine the accept my answer ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code without changing your HTML structure, check demo at:
[DEMO HERE](https://codeeditor.devsheet.com/project/8D726DE6-0F16-4223-8005-6A8793730C90)

```
<div class="entry">
    <img class="icon" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png">
    <a class="name">Inline image text will be here and it can be multi-lined</a>
    <div class="num">0</div>
</div>

<style>
.entry {
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
  color: white;
  max-width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.entry .icon {
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.entry .name {
  margin-left: 100px;
  display:block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.num {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated only your CSS. Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/AravinthAro/pen/oNNMgWB).

```
 .entry {
    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    margin: 6.9px;
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 224px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    perspective-origin: 112px 200.188px;
    transform-origin: 112px 200.188px;
    caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    min-height: 220px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items:center;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .name {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    padding-left:10px;
  }
  .num {
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 112px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit the css and include:
<style>
   .icon {
      width: 80px;
      clear: left;
      float: left;
      border-radius: 50%;
   }

   .name {
       clear: right;
       float: right;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding-top: 10px;
   }

   .num {
       clear: both;
       float: none;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 100px;
   }
<style>
```