# How to place multiple span text inline with SVG image inside an anchor?

Tags: html, css, svg

This is a noob question, and I spent 2 hrs solving this already. I have an anchor which has SVG and two span text inline. What I'm going to do is inline all the span text with SVG, but I have never reached it. I only made the first span inline with SVG, however for the second span I don't know how to place it under the first span. Can you guys help? :D

Anyway I did:

- [Making multiple lines of text inline with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788369/making-multiple-lines-of-text-inline-with-an-image) but It inline 1 span only.

```css
/* Title and Subtitle logo */
    svg {
            filter: url(#Slogo)
          }

          .logoIcon {
            vertical-align: top;
          }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      a.navbar-brand span.head-title {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      
    a.navbar-brand span.head-title::after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
    }

      a.navbar-brand span.head-subtitle {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      a.navbar-brand span.head-title {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
 a.navbar-brand span.head-title::after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
      a.navbar-brand span.head-subtitle {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
    }
```

```html
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-top:0" rel="tooltip" title="Brand" data-placement="bottom" href="<?= base_url() ?>">
            <svg xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="35pt" height="35pt" class="logoIcon" viewBox="0 0 150 150" version="1.2">
              <defs>
                <filter id="Slogo">
                  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 1 0 0 0
              0 1 0 0 0
              0 1 0 0 0
              0 1 0 1 0 " />
                </filter>
                <g>
                  <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
                    <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 12.609375 -95.546875 L 67.578125 -95.546875 L 67.578125 0 L 12.609375 0 Z M 19.40625 -6.796875 L 60.78125 -6.796875 L 60.78125 -88.75 L 19.40625 -88.75 Z M 19.40625 -6.796875 " />
                  </symbol>
                  <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
                    <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 68.421875 -26.53125 C 68.421875 -17.90625 65.316406 -11.109375 59.109375 -6.140625 C 52.898438 -1.171875 44.265625 1.3125 33.203125 1.3125 C 23.003906 1.3125 13.984375 -0.601562 6.140625 -4.4375 L 6.140625 -23.265625 C 12.585938 -20.390625 18.046875 -18.363281 22.515625 -17.1875 C 26.984375 -16.007812 31.066406 -15.421875 34.765625 -15.421875 C 39.210938 -15.421875 42.625 -16.269531 45 -17.96875 C 47.375 -19.664062 48.5625 -22.191406 48.5625 -25.546875 C 48.5625 -27.421875 48.035156 -29.085938 46.984375 -30.546875 C 45.941406 -32.003906 44.40625 -33.410156 42.375 -34.765625 C 40.351562 -36.117188 36.226562 -38.273438 30 -41.234375 C 24.15625 -43.984375 19.773438 -46.617188 16.859375 -49.140625 C 13.941406 -51.671875 11.609375 -54.613281 9.859375 -57.96875 C 8.117188 -61.320312 7.25 -65.242188 7.25 -69.734375 C 7.25 -78.179688 10.113281 -84.820312 15.84375 -89.65625 C 21.570312 -94.5 29.492188 -96.921875 39.609375 -96.921875 C 44.566406 -96.921875 49.300781 -96.332031 53.8125 -95.15625 C 58.320312 -93.976562 63.039062 -92.320312 67.96875 -90.1875 L 61.4375 -74.4375 C 56.332031 -76.53125 52.113281 -77.988281 48.78125 -78.8125 C 45.445312 -79.644531 42.171875 -80.0625 38.953125 -80.0625 C 35.117188 -80.0625 32.175781 -79.164062 30.125 -77.375 C 28.082031 -75.59375 27.0625 -73.265625 27.0625 -70.390625 C 27.0625 -68.597656 27.472656 -67.035156 28.296875 -65.703125 C 29.128906 -64.378906 30.445312 -63.097656 32.25 -61.859375 C 34.0625 -60.617188 38.34375 -58.382812 45.09375 -55.15625 C 54.019531 -50.882812 60.140625 -46.601562 63.453125 -42.3125 C 66.765625 -38.019531 68.421875 -32.757812 68.421875 -26.53125 Z M 68.421875 -26.53125 " />
                  </symbol>
                </g>
              </defs>
              <g id="surface1">
                <path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(87.059021%,67.059326%,53.729248%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 139.300781 149.542969 L 10.386719 149.542969 C 5.078125 149.542969 0.75 145.21875 0.75 139.90625 L 0.75 10.992188 C 0.75 5.683594 5.078125 1.355469 10.386719 1.355469 L 139.300781 1.355469 C 144.613281 1.355469 148.9375 5.683594 148.9375 10.992188 L 148.9375 139.90625 C 148.9375 145.21875 144.613281 149.542969 139.300781 149.542969 Z M 139.300781 149.542969 " />
                <path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 130.820312 72.535156 L 97.136719 42.921875 L 98.167969 87.742188 L 109.066406 77.109375 L 118.664062 97.703125 L 125.257812 94.609375 L 115.660156 74.058594 Z M 130.820312 72.535156 " />
                <path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 118.664062 99.273438 C 118.488281 99.273438 118.308594 99.230469 118.128906 99.183594 C 117.722656 99.050781 117.410156 98.738281 117.230469 98.378906 L 108.574219 79.800781 L 99.289062 88.867188 C 98.84375 89.3125 98.167969 89.449219 97.585938 89.179688 C 97.003906 88.957031 96.644531 88.371094 96.601562 87.742188 L 95.566406 42.964844 C 95.566406 42.335938 95.925781 41.753906 96.464844 41.484375 C 97.046875 41.214844 97.722656 41.351562 98.167969 41.753906 L 131.851562 71.367188 C 132.300781 71.769531 132.480469 72.445312 132.300781 73.027344 C 132.121094 73.609375 131.582031 74.058594 130.953125 74.105469 L 117.992188 75.359375 L 126.648438 93.933594 C 127.007812 94.742188 126.695312 95.640625 125.886719 96 L 119.292969 99.09375 C 119.113281 99.230469 118.890625 99.273438 118.664062 99.273438 Z M 109.066406 75.539062 C 109.15625 75.539062 109.246094 75.539062 109.335938 75.585938 C 109.832031 75.675781 110.277344 75.988281 110.457031 76.480469 L 119.382812 95.640625 L 123.152344 93.890625 L 114.226562 74.6875 C 114 74.238281 114.046875 73.699219 114.269531 73.25 C 114.496094 72.800781 114.988281 72.535156 115.480469 72.445312 L 127.050781 71.277344 L 98.796875 46.421875 L 99.648438 84.066406 L 107.945312 75.941406 C 108.261719 75.71875 108.664062 75.539062 109.066406 75.539062 Z M 109.066406 75.539062 " />
                <g style="fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:1;">
                  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="14.848997" y="122.254314" />
                </g>
              </g>
            </svg>
            <span class="head-title" style="">Brand Title</span>
            <span class="head-subtitle" style="">Brand Subtitle</span>
          </a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are now drawing text with a HTML -<span>, Not with a SVG tag.  Your SVG with ``viewBox="0 0 150 150"`` is a sheet of paper where ``0 0`` is upper-left and ``150 150`` is bottom-right. You can draw text on that paper with ``text`` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text And you can change that viewBox to any dimension... the width/height is set by CSS

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Well, what a good idea, okay let me try it. Thank's anyway.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman hey, I got it, available here: https://jsfiddle.net/bloodberry/aLywdemb/3/ , your suggestion was pretty cool. Instead of using span, we can use SVG immediately with the `style` tag and `text` tag, also a little bit `viewBox` / `width` / `height` modification of `svg` tag. I have to create another version (like grayscale, white, and colorized) manually, though. At least this approach worked like a charm +1

Comment: SVG is very very powerful (and complex) MDN documentation is your friend. StackOverflow usually has all the answers already, you are not the first on this voyage, learn to use advanced search... SVG has been around for some time. Have fun